# prove that $17715x^2 + 1234567x + 4561$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q} [x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I know I can suppose it is not irreducible and use Gauss' lemma to factorise $17715x^2 + 1234567x + 4561$ into two linear factors in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and try all the possible combinations (4561 is prime) to show that there is a contradiction, but it still looks clumsy. Is there any 'clean' approach? Please give me some hints, thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: Is a quadratic... Solve it and check that the zeros are irrationals

Comment: It so happens that the discriminant is 1523832485029 a prime and so certainly not a square but this is hardly easy to check.

Comment: I have tried those method, but still clumsy, I think. Thank you.

Comment: If you've further checked that 17715 and 4561 are coprime, you know the polynomial is primitive in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  The Rational Roots tests can be narrowed a bit by observing there are no positive roots (Descartes Rule of Signs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:  Reduce the polynomial mod $2$.

Comment: Thank you. I have a blind spot there.

Comment: @Longitude, you're welcome.  I think that's the point of this kind of problem, to help the scales fall from your eyes....

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the expression $\bmod 2$. What you get is $x^2+x+1$ which is obviously irreducible over $\mathbb Z_2$. Hence it is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is a field irreducibility over $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q[x]$ mean the same thing.
I've used if a polynomial after reducing the coefficients modulo $p$, with the degree remaining the same, is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_p$ for some prime $p$ then it is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I don't get this: "Since $\mathbb Q$ is a field irreducibility over $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q[x]$ mean the same thing."